# Render html based on the radio select

Tags: reactjs

I have two radio buttons and need to render a different form for each when the user click the continue button, how can I do this? Here's the code I have so far.

```js
class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      name: "typeOfInternet"
    };
    this.onChangeValue = this.onChangeValue.bind(this);
  }

  onChangeValue(event) {
    console.log(event.target.value);
  }

  handleChange = () =>
  this.setState({ showComponent: !this.state.showComponent });

  render() {
    return (
      <Container>
        <section className="section">
          <div className="tittle">
            <span>
              Vamos começar? Escolha a modalidade e preencha seus dados para
              continuar.
            </span>
          </div>
          <div className="check-block" onChange={this.onChangeValue}>
            <div className="check">
              <input
                type="radio"
                id="residencia"
                name="internet"
                value="residencial"
              />
              <label for="residencial">Internet Residencial</label>
            </div>
            <div className="check">
              <input
                type="radio"
                id="empresa"
                name="internet"
                value="empresarial"
              />
              <label for="empresarial">Internet Empresarial</label>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="continue">
            <button
              className="btn-continue"
            >
              Continue
            </button>
          </div>
        </section>
      </Container>
    )
  }
}


export default App ;
```

The difference between codes are some input fields that "imternet Empresarial" has and "Internet Residencial" does not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need for onChangeValue function because you're not calling it anywhere instead you can attach `handleChange` function to the `<input>` tags.

You should use the name which is provided in `<input>` inside `state`. So that it will be easier to use in `setState`.

There's no need to use `.bind()` also, with the help of arrow functions `=>` you can escape that.

Inside `switch`, on different cases of the values instead of using `<div>...</div>`, you can call different components present in separate file. (in order to make the component readable)

[Codesandbox Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/relaxed-black-kd273?file=/src/App.js:0-1741)

```
import { Component } from "react";

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      internet: ""
    };
  }

  handleChange = (e) => this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });

  renderForm = () => {
    switch (this.state.internet) {
      case "residencial":
        return (
          <div>
            <h1>residencial form</h1>
          </div>
        );
      case "empresarial":
        return (
          <div>
            <h1>empresarial form</h1>
          </div>
        );
      default:
        return null;
    }
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <section className="section">
        <div className="tittle">
          <span>
            Vamos começar? Escolha a modalidade e preencha seus dados para
            continuar.
          </span>
        </div>
        <div className="check-block" onChange={this.onChangeValue}>
          <div className="check">
            <input
              type="radio"
              id="residencia"
              name="internet"
              value="residencial"
              onChange={this.handleChange}
            />
            <label htmlFor="residencial">Internet Residencial</label>
          </div>
          <div className="check">
            <input
              type="radio"
              id="empresa"
              name="internet"
              value="empresarial"
              onChange={this.handleChange}
            />
            <label htmlFor="empresarial">Internet Empresarial</label>
          </div>
        </div>
        {this.renderForm()}
        <div className="continue">
          <button className="btn-continue">Continue</button>
        </div>
      </section>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to create your form element to render when radio buttons get toggled. Something like this:

```
const Form = ({ type }) => {
  return type === "residencial" ? <div>Form 1</div> : <div>Form 2</div>;
};
```

Then keep track of the currently checked radio button and whether or not the continue button has been pressed. Something like this would work ([Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/distracted-feather-6kw9f?file=/src/App.js)):

```
const Form = ({ type }) => {
  return type === "residencial" ? <div>Form 1</div> : <div>Form 2</div>;
};

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      name: "",
      step: 1
    };
  }

  onChangeValue = (event) => {
    console.log(event.target.value);
    this.setState({ name: event.target.value });
  };

  handleContinue = () => {
    this.setState({ step: 2 });
  };

  render() {
    const { step, name } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <section className="section">
          <div className="tittle">
            <span>
              Vamos começar? Escolha a modalidade e preencha seus dados para
              continuar.
            </span>
          </div>
          <div className="check-block">
            <div className="check">
              <input
                type="radio"
                id="residencia"
                name="internet"
                value="residencial"
                onChange={this.onChangeValue}
              />
              <label for="residencial">Internet Residencial</label>
            </div>
            <div className="check">
              <input
                type="radio"
                id="empresa"
                name="internet"
                value="empresarial"
                onChange={this.onChangeValue}
              />
              <label for="empresarial">Internet Empresarial</label>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="continue">
            <button
              disabled={name === ""}
              className="btn-continue"
              onClick={this.handleContinue}
            >
              Continue
            </button>
            <hr />
            {step === 2 ? <Form type={name} /> : null}
          </div>
        </section>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

There is also no need to bind your class functions, just use arrow functions, they will make your life much easier.